# Restrict navigation bar from hide on button tap

Tags: ios, swift, button, uinavigationbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I wants to hide navigation bar on tap. So i used this method of navigation bar.

```
 self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

Have 2 button on screen and when i tap on that button for perform some action it is also hiding navigation bar. I think button click consider as tap.

Can you please let me know, is it correct behaviour ? Also please let me know if there is any way to restrict this. I don't want to hide navigation bar on button tap, rest of parts of screen will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom button and handle touches on to enable/disable hiding bars e.g.:

```swift
class BarHideOnTapButton : UIButton {
    weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var button: BarHideOnTapButton?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.button?.navigationController = self.navigationController

        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Have you set class `BarHideOnTapButton` in your storyboard or xib for your button?

Comment: This solution works for me. Try to set breakpoints inside touchesBegan and touchesEnded to be sure that they are called on button click.